# Where does Firefox webauthn softtoken save its key?

Tags: firefox, webauthn

GitHub is pushing 2FA and offer mostly unreasonable choices; however there is webauthn and Firefox has a [software version of it](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21963399); so a proper security mode can be built.

But in order to do this I need to know where the token is stored so I can back it up, restore it, encrypt it, etc.

Depending on how Firefox implemented it I'm hoping to decrypt it to a ramdrive only when needed.

Answer (score 2):

The softtoken stores the wrapping key in the NSS key database, which is an SQLite3 database called key4.db inside your Firefox Profile directory.

You can find your Firefox profile directory by visiting about:support in the browser.

Comment: This the document for it? https://wiki.mozilla.org/NSS_Shared_DB